# Is not `.length` the right way to check whether an array is empty or not in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following AJAX call:

```
$('#fileupload').show().fileupload({
    url: '/upload',
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        var error_msg = $("#load_error_msg");

        error_msg.html('');

        if (data.result.error.length > 0) {
            // process errors messages here 
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    },
})
```

The upload method on the backend return a JSON like the following:

```
{
  "error": {
    "fileUploadErrorIniSize": "File '' exceeds the defined ini size"
  }
}
```

The code is bypassing this checking `data.result.error.length` and going always trough the `else` condition.

I am confused at this point: is not `.length` the right way to check whether an array is empty or not in Javascript? If it's not which is the right way?

Comment: It is correct way for arrays but `error` is an object literal

Comment: check in console log whats is data.result and data.result.log and check the value of data.result.error.length too

Comment: `if (data.result.error)` Must do too..

Comment: `.length` is for size of a *collection* like array... here you can try `Object.keys(data.result.error).length`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an array, it's a plain object. Plain objects don't have a `length` property by default.

You can use `Object.keys(data.result.error).length` to see if it has any own, enumerable properties, which your example will have.

E.g., assuming `data.result` really points to that data structure, then:

```
if (Object.keys(data.result.error).length > 0) {
```

If there's any possibility that `data.result` won't have an `error` property at all, you'll want to guard against that:

```
if (data.result.error && Object.keys(data.result.error).length > 0) {
```

But if you know it'll always be there (just sometimes empty), there's no need.